# Merge 2 pandas dataframes - python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframes:

data1=

| sample ID | name | sex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | male |
| 1 | b | male |
| 2 | c | male |
| 3 | d | male |
| 4 | e | male |

data2=

| samples | Diabetic | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | yes | 43 |
| 1 | yes | 50 |
| 2 | no | 63 |
| 3 | no | 21 |
| 4 | yes | 44 |

I want to merge both data frames to end up with the following data frame

| samples | Diabetic | age | name | sex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | yes | 43 | a | male |
| 1 | yes | 50 | b | male |
| 2 | no | 63 | c | male |
| 3 | no | 21 | d | male |
| 4 | yes | 44 | e | male |

Comment: `data2.merge(data1, left_on='samples', right_on='sample ID')`?

Comment: I tried this line but it does the dataframe stays unchanged, I even tried data2 = data2.merge(data1, left_on='samples', right_on='sample ID')

Comment: Yes, if you want to save it as a new dataframe, you need to assign it with `new_df = data2.merge(...)` where `new_df` is the name of the dataframe you want to save it to

Comment: the ‘new_df’ is empty with nothing saved.

Comment: Could it be that there are no matches between `sample ID` in `data1` and `samples` in `data2`?

Comment: thanks for point that out, the datatype of the sample ID of both data frames were object, I converted them to int and that worked perfectly!

Comment: Thank you very much :)